# How to call method from background thread on main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a console application in which I create a worker (background) thread. After thread finished I want to execute a method on main thread.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        private void ProcessTask()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessTask: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Action onFinished = OnTaskFinished;
            onFinished.Invoke();
        }

        private void OnTaskFinished()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnTaskFinished: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            Program program = new Program();
            Thread thread = new Thread(program.ProcessTask);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

But OnTaskFinished method is executed on the background thread, not on the main thread.
Application writes to console the following output:

```
Main: 9
ProcessTask: 10
OnTaskFinished: 10
```

But I want to:

```
Main: 9
ProcessTask: 10
OnTaskFinished: 9
```

What is the right solution for this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want that?

Answer (score 2):

Console applications do not have a "Main Thread" like UI applications that you can invoke to. Switch your project from a console application to a windowed application then switch your `onFinished.Invoke();` to use the UI frameworks' invoke (WPF and Winforms do it differently).

There are also classes to make this easier like [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx), also using async/await also makes this easy.

```
private async Task StartProcessTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine("StartProcessTask: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    await Task.Run(()=>ProcessTask());
    OnTaskFinished();
}

private void ProcessTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine("ProcessTask: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}

private void OnTaskFinished()
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnTaskFinished: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

Comment: I forgot, that an application must be compiled in .NET 3.5, so async/await can not be used and it is an application without user interaction.

Comment: Ok, in that case there is no "Main thread" to go back to. Usually when people say "Main Thread" what they really mean is "A thread with a message pump running", console applications do not have a message pump. It sounds like you are falling in to a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please update your question explaining ***why*** you want to run the code after the background finishes "on the main thread" and we can help you accomplish that goal in a console program.

Comment: Bringing in a UI framework just to marshal a call across threads?! The intention of the OP is unclear to me.